# Arduino Led Cube 5x5x5 shift register 74HC595

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I'm working on an Arduino project led cube 5x5x5 using shift register 74HC595 I write a function to turn one led on or off the problem is when I want to turn on two led in different layer 4 led turn on how I can solve that

```
#include <ShiftRegister74HC595.h>
// create a global shift register object
// parameters: <number of shift registers> (data pin, clock pin, latch pin)
ShiftRegister74HC595<4> sr(11, 13, 8);
const uint8_t L0 = A0;const uint8_t L1 = A1;
const uint8_t L2 = A2;const uint8_t L3 = A3;
const uint8_t L4 = A4;
static const uint8_t layers[] = {L0,L1,L2,L3,L4};
const int delaytime=10;
void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    pinMode(layers[i],OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    setLedState(0,L4,true); 
    setLedState(12,L1,true);
}

void setLedState(int lednum,uint8_t layer,bool state)
{
 if(state==true)
 {
   sr.set(lednum,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(layer,HIGH);
 }else
 {
   sr.set(lednum,LOW);
   digitalWrite(layer,LOW);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you find a solution to your problem? Posting a wiring schematic might have been useful